# can not send request in parse callback in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

i have a class to **scrape** some data:

```
class SiteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "somesite"
    start_urls = ['https://www.somesite.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        parser = CommentParser()
        urls = ['https://www.somesite.com']
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=parser.scrape)
```

which in CommentParser class i have:

```
class CommentParser():
    def scrape(self, response):
        print("from CommentParser.scrape =>", response.url)
        for i in range(5):
            yield scrapy.Request(url="https://www.somesite.com/comments/?page=%d" % i, callback=self.parse)
    
    def parse(self,response):
        print("from CommentParser.parse => ", response.url)
        yield dict(response_url = response.url)
```

but scrapy dose not send request in CommentParser class and so i can not get response in CommentParser.parse

Comment: Any particular reason you need to classes like this?

Comment: yes, i want to parse each segment of site in one class. for example a class for comment,another one for headline, another for body, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to play with OOP, notice `SiteSpider(CommentParser):` that means `SiteSpider` will have access to methods of `CommentParser`

```
class CommentParser(scrapy.Spider):
    def scrape(self, response):
        print("from CommentParser.scrape =>", response.url)
        for i in range(5):
            yield scrapy.Request(url="https://www.somesite.com/comments/?page=%d" % i, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self,response):
        print("from CommentParser.parse => ", response.url)
        yield dict(response_url = response.url)

class SiteSpider(CommentParser):
    name = "somesite"
    start_urls = ['https://www.somesite.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://www.somesite.com']
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.scrape) #This will call CommentParser's scrape method
```